# Cannot get moq to create a instance from a type - "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Tags: .net, moq, createinstance

I'm trying to use Moq to stub a data class which I want to be created dynamically through Activator.CreateInstance when I pass its type (via Moq.Object.GetType() where Moq is the stub instance) but I get `System.MissingMethodException {"No parameterless constructor defined for this object."}`

What am I doing wrong? I don't want to change my subject code to accommodate for Moq.

**Test**

```
private Test() ...
{
   var recordStub = new Mock<IRecord>();
   var record = recordStub.Object;
   var recordDefinition = new RecordDefinition() 
                              { MappedRecordClassType = record.GetType(), ... 

   var newRecord = CreateDataRecord(recordDefinition);
   ...
}
```

**Subject**

```
private IRecord CreateDataRecord(RecordDefinition recordDefinition)
{
   var result = Activator.CreateInstance(recordDefinition.MappedRecordClassType) 
                       as IRecord;
   return result;
}
```

Comment: does `MappedRecordClassType` have a default constructor with no parameters ?

Comment: MappedRecordClassType is simply a parameter of type System.Type. The data class of this type is what is being mocked i.e. new Mock<IRecord>() so the constructor is the one generated by Moq I presume.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an instance of `record.GetType()` and since `record = recordStub.Object` which is an object dynamically generated by Moq at run-time that implements `IRecord` in your situation then what you are essentially doing is creating an instance of a dynamically generated object and it seems that `Activator.CreateInstance()` can't find a public constructor that takes no arguments on that type. Now i don't know why are you doing what you are doing but i have never seen anyone using a Mock like that so i think you should reconsider your test.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code Moq is trying to instantiate an object that you have either not mocked out or is exposed as a class directly. Either way said object has no public constructor that has 0 parameters.

You will need to track down where in your test the object with no public 0 parameter constructors is being called and either fix it or otherwise work around it.

I ran into the same thing on a recent project and in most cases we were surfacing an object as the class itself instead of the interface.

Comment: I have mocked concrete classes and have got this message when I haven't passed in the arguments the class expects in the constructor when instantiating the Moq but in this case the stub is of an interface I'd expect the dynamic class Moq generates just has a parameterless constructor (i.e. descend from Object).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sniffer. What you're doing is passing in the `typeof IRecord`, and then asking your Activator to create an instance of it. But, it's an Interface, so you cannot create an instance of it directly, you need a concrete class in order do to that.

If there is value in this test, what you will need to do is create an old-school, hand-written stub... that is, an almost empty class that simply implements your `IRecord` interface and returns values (does no real work) that your tests need.

But, then really all you are doing is testing that `Activator.CreateInstance` can find that type and create an instance of it, and I agree with Sniffer, you're basically testing out 3rd party code. You probably do not nor should not cover this method.

Comment: I thought Moq (behind the scenes) is actually creating a class that implements the IRecord interface. Hence GetType() should be giving me an the Type of this class. As a workaround I have written a manual Stub but I do think something is still amiss here but I was trying to find out how Moq operates and whether this may be an issue in some more dynamic coding constructs.

Comment: Moq creates an instance of a class that implements that interface, and defaults to loose behavior, so that on that instance of the mock, you can tell it whatever and it most likely will not crash. However, you are passing the type of that object, which is the interface IRecord, into your method that calls `Activator.CreateInstance()` so your code is actually saying *"Activator, create an instance of the type IRecord"*. This causes the runtime error because you cannot create the instance of an interface. You can test this by removing Moq and passing in `typeof(IRecord)` and see the same result.